# Substracting the n value in date()

Tags: php, date, date-math

I want to implement a Javascript countdown timer that has the month value substracted by 1.

To get the date dynamically via PHP I use this code:

```
$date = "2014:3:19 00:00:00";
$newDate = date("Y, n, j, H, i", strtotime($date));
```

Which returns:

```
2014, 3, 9, 00
```

My question is how can I substract the value `n` by 1, so the final output will be always like this:

```
2014, (3-1), 9, 00
```

Comment: do u want out out (n-1) or the result of (n-1)?

Comment: hi Jason, I want the result of n-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean minus one month, then you could do:

```
$date = "2014-3-19 00:00:00";
$newDate = date("Y, n, j, H, i", strtotime('-1 month', strtotime($date)));
```

And `2014, 1, 19, 00` will be `2013, 12, 19, 00` but not `2014, 0, 19, 00`.

---

***Update:***

You want to pass a date to the jQuery plugin([jquery.magicbusmultimedia.net](http://jquery.magicbusmultimedia.net/)).

The plugin only ask you to pass a javascript Date object.

So you could do:

```
$('#myCounter').mbComingsoon(new Date(<?php echo strtotime($date); ?> * 1000));
```

Comment: Umm how to get result 2014, 0, 19, 00, not 2013, 12, 19, 00 ?

Comment: @zoora There is no month zero

Comment: @zoora Could you tell me first why you want month zero?

Comment: @John yes exactly, but the javascript countdown code I used asking me to enter the month value substracted by -1 :( It's http://jquery.magicbusmultimedia.net/

Comment: @zoora As I expected, javascript Date issue. Then, you should not do it in php, just do it in javascript, and i even think you don't have to format the date in php.

Comment: @xdazz ahh ... so should I use other javascript countdown script?

Comment: @zoora See my updated answer. You could construct the js Date object from unix timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the `DateTime()` way to do it (I used dashes instead of colons as that is the proper separator for date parts):

```
$date = "2014-3-19 00:00:00";
$date = (new DateTime($date))->modify('-1 month')->format("Y, n, j, H, i");
```

or

```
$date = "2014-3-19 00:00:00";
$date = (new DateTime($date))->diff(new DateInterval('P1M'))->format("Y, n, j, H, i");
```

Answer (score 0):

$date = "2014-3-19 00:00:00";
$newDate = date("Y, n, j, H, i", strtotime('-1 month', strtotime($date)));
And 2014, 1, 19, 00 will be 2013, 12, 19, 00 but not 2014, 0, 19, 00.